# What is the corresponding method of WebViewClient's "shouldInterceptRequest" in Chromium Browser Code?

Tags: android, webview, chromium, webviewclient, webchromeclient

I'm working on a *WebView Based Browser*. I want to change its renderer to *Chromium* so I am mapping methods overridden from WebView, WebView Client, and Web Chrome Client in my Browser Code to those in Chromium code. I can't find the mapping of `shouldInterceptRequest` of WebView Client in Chromium code. How does Chromium handle `shouldInterceptRequest`?

I have tried to find intercepting functionality in Chromium code by searching some keywords but haven't yet found any matches. Also, there is a method shouldInterceptNavigation in Chromium that I found which was looking close to the functionality of shouldInterceptRequest, but while debugging that method doesn't get called in the scenarios where shouldInterceptRequest gets called.

Is there any method corresponding to `shouldInterceptRequest` in Chromium Code or some other way Chromium code is handling this functionality?

Comment: this method has nothing to do with renderring. If your aim is the rendering, you can just skip this method

Comment: My aim is to replace WebView with Chromium. My Browser has few functionalities to be done at every intercepted URL resource, which I want to retain when I use Chromium. So where exactly should I add my policy functionality in Chromium code which is added in shouldInterceptRequest.